# UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username while updating user info

Tags: django, django-users

I am trying to give a user the option to change his/her first/last name through a ModelForm. When I press submit, I get hit with the *UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username* error. Here are my codes:

students/forms.py:

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    def clean_password(self):
        # Overriding the default method because I dont want user to change 
        # password
        pass

     class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
        )
```

students/views.py:

```
User = get_user_model()

def student_profile_view(request, slug):
    if request.method == 'GET':

        # forms
        edit_name_form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)

        context = {
            'edit_name_form': edit_name_form,
        }
        return render(request, "students/profile.html", context)

class ChangeNameView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
        template_name = 'students/edit_profile.html'
        model = User
        form_class = EditProfileForm
        success_message = "Your name has been updated"

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = self.get_form()
            if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.student_profile = StudentProfile.objects.get(slug=request.user.student_profile.slug)
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)

        def form_valid(self, form):
            """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
            form.instance.username = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            return super().form_valid(form)

        def get_success_url(self):
            return reverse('students:student_profile_view', kwargs={'slug': self.object.student_profile.slug})
```

also fyi, User model is foreign key with StudentProfile.

students/models.py:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='student_profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='student_profile/', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("students:student_profile_view", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

I am pretty new to class based view so maybe I'm doing something wrong there?

Comment: I think you can just get rid of the post function

Comment: thanks but the error still remains

Comment: Sorry - just realised the issue isn't that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you do not have the user within the form so you need the form

```
def get_context_data (self, *args, **kwargs)
    ctx = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        ctx['form'] = EditProfileForm(instance=self.request.user)
```

and remove `def form_valid()`